# Facebook-connect database storage

Tags: database, facebook

Can Facebook-Connect on a site do everything a normal sign-up login process can?

Every person has there own database I.D for uploading/downloading, Saving info, saved message's, new messages ect.

You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your coding skillz for your back-end that you will need to wrap around the facebook login.  Facebook-Connect wont do that part for you.